# joomla login module won't fire credentials send it threw ajax!

Tags: jquery, ajax, module, joomla

I'm trying to make an jquery ajax modal login module for joomla 1.6. There should be so that the credentials passed threw ajax to be proofed by a php file.
But fortunately doesn't seem to be executed. My ajax looks as it follows

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",
url: "do-login.php",  // Send the login info to this page
data: "username="+$('#username').val()+"&password="+$('#password').val(),   
success: function(msg){  }
```

and the receiver php file

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
/* Initialize Joomla framework */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport( 'joomla.application.application' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$post_username = JRequest::getVar($username);
$post_password = JRequest::getVar($password);



$data['username'] =$post_username;
$data['password'] = $post_password;

$mainframe->login($data, $option);
if (!JError::isError($error)) {
        echo 'OK';
    } else {
          echo '<div id="notification_error">The login info is not correct.</div>';

    }





?>
```

If I'm removing joomla defined(`_JEXEC`)code than are not loaded the specific classes.

---

I thought so. Everything has to go through joomla's index.php. 
But what about if I'm using the standard joomla com_users component can I achieve  my objectives?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call the PHP files directly; you're trying to do exactly  what the `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` bit is designed to prevent ;)

You're going to need to build a component to receive those calls, then spit back the response you want to display. Assuming (for the sake of discussion) you build `com_ajax_login` as your component, your JavaScript would look like this:

```
$.post('index.php', {
    option: 'com_ajax_login',
    tmpl: 'component',
    format: 'raw',
    username: $('#username').val(),
    password: $('#password').val(),
    },
  function(response){
    $('#your_login_box').html(response);
});
```

When the component spits out the response, it will get passed into that anonymous function with the parameter `response`, then you can place it wherever you want (like `$('#your_login_box').html(response);` for example). Also note the `format` and `tmpl` variables in the request: these prevent Joomla from returning the full template.

You could pretty much copy `do-login.php` into `components/com_ajax_login/ajax_login.php` as-is (although you'll need to either install the component through the Joomla installer or make an entry in `jos_extensions`).

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I thought so. Everything has to go through joomla's index.php. But what about if I'm using the standard joomla com_users component can I achieve my objectives?

Comment: I'm not sure. The standard com_users component throws in a redirect. I believe (although not 100% certain) this is done to make sure that the cookie gets set before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following format for your post query?

```
$.post('do-login.php', { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()}, function (data) {

});
```